# No exe file being generated in C using recent Cygwin versions

Tags: c, windows, gcc, cygwin

GCC 4.9.2 does not create an executable, neither `a.out` or `-o hello.exe`.  Adding `-v` to the compile line indicates that `-o` is switched to a non-existent temporary file, for example: `-o /tmp/ccr6nMlO.s`

Recent installs of Cygwin NT-6.1 over the last few months onto both Windows XP and Windows 7 have all failed to produce an executable.  I found Cygwin 1.7.3 on an old laptop that works perfectly.

Have the compile flags or their syntax changed? This command fails to generate an executable:

```
gcc hello.c -o hello.exe
```

This is the version I have. I thought it came from a Cygwin mirror. `$ uname -a` gives

```
CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW Gary-PC 1.7.35(0.287/5/3) 2015-03-04 12:07 i686
```

Here's a compile example:

```
$ gcc hello.c -o hello.exe
```

`echo $?` returns a `1`, without comment. So the compiler is failing.

All attempts to compile any code fails to produce anything in the current directory and no errors or warnings are reported. `ctgcheck -c bash binutils bzip2 cygwin gcc-core gcc-g++ gzip m4 make unzip zip` indicates everything is installed:

```
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
bash                 4.3.33-1       OK
binutils             2.25-1         OK
bzip2                1.0.6-2        OK
cygwin               1.7.35-1       OK
gcc-core             4.9.2-3        OK
gcc-g++              4.9.2-3        OK
gzip                 1.6-1          OK
m4                   1.4.17-1       OK
make                 4.1-1          OK
unzip                6.0-14         OK
```

Compiling with `-v` gives this report:

```
$ gcc hello.c -o hello.exe -v

Using built-in specs. 
COLLECT_GCC=gcc 
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/lto-wrapper.exe 
Target: i686-pc-cygwin 
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-4.9.2-3.i686/src/gcc-4.9.2/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-4.9.2-3.i686/src/gcc-4.9.2 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --datadir=/usr/share --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --libdir=/usr/lib --datarootdir=/usr/share --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=i686-pc-cygwin --host=i686-pc-cygwin --target=i686-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,java,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --enable-libssp --enable-libada --enable-libjava --enable-libgcj-sublibs --disable-java-awt --disable-symvers --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/ecj.jar --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id 
Thread model: posix gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'hello.exe' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686' /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/cc1.exe -quiet -v -Dunix -idirafter /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../include/w32api -idirafter /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/lib/../../include/w32api hello.c -quiet -dumpbase hello.c -mtune=generic -march=i686 -auxbase hello -version -o /tmp/cc8W4cOy.s
```

I've also installed Cygwin on Windows XP that reports this version: `CYGWIN_NT-5.1 lt-love6 1.7.35(0.287/5/3) 2015-03-04 12:07 i686 Cygwin`

The compile results for `hello.c` are the same. No executable is made and `$?=1` indicating the compile has failed. Also there are no reported errors or warnings. Using `-v` provides a report similar to the one above.

Comment: Are there any errors when you run gcc, or does it return a non-zero return code? Does this happen for every source file, or just for the hello.c example you gave? Do you use any libraries, if so which ones?

Comment: If you are installing Cygwin NT-6.1, that's not the correct installation and I don't even know where you got that. Are you using the installer from the cygwin web site? Also, I don't recall if cygwin executables run as a .exe or whether it must be a .out

Comment: @Rob: Cygwin executables are named with a `.exe` suffix. Cygwin lets a file with a `.exe` suffix be referred to by its base name; for example `hello` and `hello.exe` are the same file.

Comment: I believe the name "NT-6.1" refers to Windows 7. There is no single version number for Cygwin. The temporary file `/tmp/ccr6nMlO.s` is normal; that's the assembly language file that's assembled to a `.o` file, which is then linked into an executable. Does the `gcc` command produce any messages? Is there a file named `hello.exe` in the current directory?

Comment: "Have the compile flags or their syntax changed?" No. Something is wrong with your Cygwin and/or gcc configuration. Try reinstalling gcc, and remember that "NT-6.1" is not a Cygwin version number.

Comment: I have re-installed gcc-core and gcc-++ as suggested. Nothing has changed. No executable is made compiling: gcc hello.c and the exit code, e.i., $?, is 1 indicating gcc failed.  No one has addressed this problem.

Comment: @RichSedman: do you have the *gcc* version (`gcc -v`)? Also *Cygwin* version. This is not reproducible with newer *gcc* versions.

Comment: I remember cygwin and mingw to be a buggy mess. Only thinks I can think of I either use MSVC or switch platform, or to open a bug ticket / write a mail in their bug reporting mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem (and started a bounty) but have now managed to resolve my own problem by re-installing Cygwin. @CristiFati added a comment to the question asking for clarification of versions but ironically, having added a bounty leaves me with insufficient reputation to be able to reply - so I'll have to answer here instead.

Cygwin setup was used to bring the system up to date and to install the GCC packages (by adding package 'gcc-objc++') as the original Cygwin was installed without GCC support. However, this installation was on a system with multiple users running with restricted privileges. I believe that this interfered with the upgrade and resulted in some files being inaccessible to some users and so the installation of GCC was corrupt.

The behavior was that a successful compilation worked and produced the correct object files but any errors would silently fail, with no output and no error messages (but an exit status of '1').

The solution was to completely remove Cygwin and re-install as my own user. This ensured the permissions were correct so the installation/upgrade could correctly upgrade all files and GCC compilation and error reporting is now working as expected.

**To summarize**:

- Incorrect Windows permissions caused package installation issues.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are only interested in having a working system (in which case you could simply reinstall Cygwin, possibly a newer version),
or in being certain about forensics, i.e., determining the cause of your problem.

For the second objective, one thing you could do is isolating the 3 phases of going from hello.c to hello.exe:

1. Preprocessing (using `-v` for verbosity)

   ```
   gcc -E hello.c -v -o hello.i
   ```
2. Compiling

   ```
   gcc -c hello.c -v -o hello.o
   ```

(or you could also compile hello.i)

3. Linking

   ```
   gcc hello.o -v -o hello.exe
   ```

and checking which of the three fails first.
That may give you a clue on possible sources of failure.

PS: I cannot reproduce your problem with

```
$ uname -a
MSYS_NT-10.0-WOW P522806 2.11.2(0.329/5/3) 2018-11-26 08:59 i686 Msys

$ gcc --version
gcc.exe (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 8.2.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 0):

As per I've used, a simple GCC command in Cygwin terminal as

```
$ gcc filename.c
```

produces output file "a". You can run it as follows:

```
$ ./a
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the version I have. It came from a cygwin mirror. 
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW Gary-PC 1.7.35(0.287/5/3) 2015-03-04 12:07 i686 Cygwin

Comment: `gcc filename.c` creates a file called `a.exe`. That file can also be referred to as `a`. The `-o` option specifies the name of the output file. The command given in the question *should* work.

Comment: Nothing is created in the current directory. Not a.out, a.exe, or anything by any name.

Comment: I get nothing and the return code is 1 indicating gcc failed.

Comment: @red69: If you want me to see a comment, mention my name following an @ sign. Without that, I probably won't be notified. I only saw this because I happened to check the question again. If you include the output of `gcc -v` *formatted as code* (copy-and-paste and use the `{}` icon), we might be able to help.

Comment: @Keith Thompson Sorry for the problems, I'm still learning the web interface. For example, This won't look good because a carraige return exits the comment window rather than creating a new line. The results of gcc -v are too large to insert into a comment which is why I used "Add Another Question" earlier. I ran "cygcheck -c bash binutils bzip2 cygwin gcc4-core gcc4-g++ gzip m4 make unzip zip." There was no report for gcc4-core and gcc4-g++. Everything else reported OK. How do I get the results of gcc -v to you?

Comment: Don't get it *to me*; I'm not necessarily the person who will be  able to answer the question. Edit the question and update it with the output. Be sure to copy-and-paste it, and format it as code.

Comment: @Keith Thompson Thanks for the copy-paste advice into the original message. Is there a tutorial how to use this site? It doesn't retain my formatting and I don't see the  {} icon you refer to?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.